# How to set focus on an element inside a MessageDialog

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, devexpress

I'm building a windows store app and i'm using the DevExpress tools to make it happen. But i'm thinking this problem might have a general solution. When i'm opening the dialog i want to set focus on a textbox so that you can instantly begin typing.

I wonder if i can by the XAML set a default field, or if i simply have to do it by code, and if i have to do it by code, how do i do it?

I don't have much code to show but:

Code:

```
var dialog = _serviceContainer.GetService<IDXDialogService>("InputDialog");
dialog.Content = aModel;
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();      
if (result == MessageDialogResult.OK)
{
//woho, check input
}
```

XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InputDialogContentTemplate">
    <TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Input,
                            Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <dc:DXDialogService Key="ScanInputDialog"
                        Buttons="OKCancel"
                        Title="Input Something"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InputDialogContentTemplate}"
                        DefaultDialogButton="Ok" />
```

Comment: Depending what you're working in, `TabIndex="0"` on your object you wish to have initial focus could work...but is this SL/WPF, etc?

Comment: The tags indicate WinRT, so not SL or WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the datatemplate content into a usercontrol. In the usercontrol i added a Loaded event and set the focus on the textbox there. Works like a charm!